# adding zeroes before decimal place in R

Tags: r, format

I've used formatC to adding leading zeroes when needed but I'm currently working with census tracts that require I add trailing zeroes with no decimal.  I've read through the options but can't see a way formatC places the zeroes to the end without making them decimals places? Any thoughts are much appreciated.

```
tract<-c(1,11,101,1001,10001,100001)
formatC(tract,width=6,format="d",flag="0")
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pad with leading zeros to common width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409084/pad-with-leading-zeros-to-common-width)

Comment: `gsub("\\s","0",formatC(tract,format="f",flag="-",digits=0,width=6))` was the best I could muster when using formatC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add trailing zeros with `str_pad` from the `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)
str_pad(tract, 6, "right", "0")
# [1] "100000" "110000" "101000" "100100" "100010" "100001"
```

Answer (score 1):

With `stringi`:

```
library(stringi)
stri_pad_right(tract, 6, "0")
```