# How to convert 0 to 00 in R?

Tags: r, excel, forms, csv, rstudio

Hello? I would like to ask a question on R code.

First, here is my raw Excel data, which is a CSV file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hcQt.jpg)

As you can see this photo, zeros in List_code and List_code_2 are written at the very front. However, when I load the CSV file in R studio, zeros disappear. I add a photo on R studio result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDhTP.jpg)

I would like to change numbers like Excel shows. For example, '1475' in List_code and '0' in List_code_2 are needed to convert into '01475' and '00', but '45876' and '10' do not need to change the forms. I tried format() function, but it didn't work. Here is my R codes.

`Barcode <- read.csv("Fruit_barcode.csv", header=T)
 View(Barcode)
 format(Barcode$List_code, format="%Y")`

How can I change the code number forms in R data frame?
I am looking forward to seeing some answers. Thank you so much.

Comment: Or this     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409084/pad-with-leading-zeros-to-common-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `colClasses`, to set all columns as text :

```
read.csv("datafile.csv", colClasses=rep("character", 7))
```

Comment: I really really appreciate your help. It works!!!! Thank you so much, and have a nice day today! :-)