# R : find a pattern and edit

Tags: r, regex, text-processing, stringr

I am *aware of all of the questions* regarding the Adding `leading zero` and the *comprehensive responses* provided for them such as [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r/5812607#5812607), [Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14409084/pad-with-leading-zeros-to-common-width), [Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266915/format-number-as-fixed-width-with-leading-zeros).

But to me , at least based on my current knowledge, I am not able to address what I am going to do as follow:

- add the `leading zero` in a `string` using `regex` pattern match 
  So, I want to add `leading zero` only to `digits` after the `-`.

for example :

```
Sam <- c("222-88", "537-457", "652-1", "787-892")
var <- LETTERS[1:4]
DF<- data.frame(Sam, var)
DF
      Sam var
1  222-88   A
2  537-457  B
3  652-1    C
4  787-892  D
```

Expected results:

```
     Sam   var
1  222-088   A
2  537-457   B
3  652-001   C
4  787-892   D
```

I tried :

```
library(stringr)
temp <- DF[str_detect(DF$Sam, "-[0-9]{1,2}$"),] # will find the rows need the leading zero
temp 
     Sam var
1 222-88   A
3  652-1   C

formatC(temp$Sam, width = 2,flag = 0)# not correct!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `base R`, by splitting the string by `-` and then use `sprintf` to pad the 0's after converting to `numeric` and then `paste`

```
DF$Sam <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(DF$Sam), "-"), function(x) 
       paste(x[1],sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(x[2])), sep="-"))
DF$Sam
#[1] "222-088" "537-457" "652-001" "787-892"
```

---

If we need a regex approach we can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+)$", ~sprintf("%03d", as.numeric(x)), as.character(DF$Sam))
#[1] "222-088" "537-457" "652-001" "787-892"
```

Comment: Thnk, Can we do it with `stringr` or any other `packages`? another words is there any other easier alternatives?

Comment: @Daniel Updated with a `gsubfn` approach which uses `sprintf` so that it will prevent any errors

Answer (score 3):

Another base option

```
Sam <- c("222-88", "537-457", "652-1", "787-892")
m <- gregexpr("[0-9]+$", Sam)
regmatches(Sam, m) <- sprintf('%03s', unlist(regmatches(Sam, m)))
Sam

# [1] "222-088" "537-457" "652-001" "787-892"
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative in Base R is

```
DF$Sam = sub("-(\\d)\\b", "-00\\1", DF$Sam)
DF$Sam = sub("-(\\d\\d)\\b", "-0\\1", DF$Sam)
DF
      Sam var
1 222-088   A
2 537-457   B
3 652-001   C
4 787-892   D
```

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with `tidyverse` you can try:

```r
Sam <- c("222-88", "537-457", "652-1", "787-892")
var <- LETTERS[1:4]
df <- data.frame(Sam, var)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  separate(Sam, c("sam1", "sam2")) %>% 
  mutate(Sam = str_c(sam1, "-", str_pad(sam2, 3, "left", "0"))) %>% 
  select(-sam1, -sam2)

#>   var     Sam
#> 1   A 222-088
#> 2   B 537-457
#> 3   C 652-001
#> 4   D 787-892

# OR

df %>% 
  mutate(
    sam_new = str_c(
      str_extract(Sam, "^\\d+-"),
      str_extract(Sam, "\\d+$") %>% str_pad(3, "left", "0")
    )
  )

#>       Sam var sam_new
#> 1  222-88   A 222-088
#> 2 537-457   B 537-457
#> 3   652-1   C 652-001
#> 4 787-892   D 787-892
```